# A-Frame <a-image> distorted on some browser in some device

Tags: javascript, html, three.js, aframe

<a-image> image distorted on the device-browser below:

IOS: *Google Chrome*

Android: *default Internet browser*

I've tried both scale and width/height as below but still doesnt scale or re-size to the right size I wanted.

```
<a-image width="1.365" height="2.2" position="0 0 -5" src="./chicken1.png" material="alpha-test: .5" shadow></a-image>
```

and

```
<a-image scale="1.7 1.35 1" position="0 0 -5" src="./chicken1.png" material="alpha-test: .5" shadow></a-image>
```

Also a reference of the actual issue [here](http://tech.campaignizer.com/SampleImageSizingAR/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the original pixels of the image?

Also when resizing images try to keep the aspect ratio of the image to remove the distortion, if the image is **1280 x 720 pixels** then try to resize based off of this, try not to stretch/reshape the image.

Personally i would only resize an image using pixels like **height="200px"** try and do the formatting within CSS also.

Comment: Thanks, I think i got it but still slightly distorted tho between different browsers. Also CSS formatting isn't possible as a-frame is using the image in canvas.

But still, thanks @connorg98!